# while loop skipping query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, while-loop

my while loop skip the element. looked for similar questions but still cannot understand. enlighten me please. tnx!

```
$query = "SELECT userid, COUNT(content) as x_count
                       FROM x GROUP BY userid ORDER BY x_count DESC
                       LIMIT 5";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error in query:".mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            echo '<br>';
            while(list($id,$no_x) = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo $id.'number of x:'.$no_x;
                echo '<br>';
            }
```

Comment: What is "the element?"

Comment: `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`, do not call this.

Comment: All `mysql_` functions are deprecated. http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated. Use [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: Unless you're working on some legacy application, learning how to use `mysql_query` is a waste of time. This interface is being phased out and will be removed entirely in future versions of PHP. PDO takes about half an hour to learn, there's no excuse not to use it if you can.

Comment: IMO we should setup something that would notify all tutorial writers to add a big fat red box saying mysql_* is deprecated!

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. yep im on a mysql legacy app. ill use PDO in my future apps. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're executing `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`, this will advance the result set.

I cannot see why you're calling this, so my suggestion is to just remove this line.